# Does Idris have MaybeT?

Tags: haskell, idris

Does Idris have `MaybeT` from Haskell or is there something else I should use instead? I am trying to do computations with many values of type `IO (Maybe a)`. How can combine `Maybe` and `IO` into a single monad (like `MaybeT IO` in Haskell) in Idris?

Comment: Voting to reopen, as the question is not that unclear. I won't be surprised, though, if it is reclosed for other reasons. (Questions asking if language X has feature Y are a grey area between on- and off-topic.)

Comment: I think, though, that you want to use the [Effects library](http://docs.idris-lang.org/en/latest/effects/index.html).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's a new PR adding it, though it hasn't been merged yet: https://github.com/idris-lang/Idris-dev/pull/4753